# Lua NGINX String find multi lines

Tags: nginx, lua, lua-table, openresty

i'm having lua program that i'm reading some files

but they are in .csv format, which I need to find some string.

When it's having multi-lines doesn't work, only first line is available.

Using :

```
   local open_file = io.open(file, "r")
   local data = open_file:read()
   io.close(open_file)
```

And displaying :

```
local  match0 = string.find(string1, data)
```

So it's reading only first line in my .csv

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should give string.gsub([pattern], [string | table | function], [count]) a try.
For example, to remove all newlines to return a single line choose...

```
local open_file = io.open(file) -- read is the default
local data, count = open_file:read('*a'):gsub('\n', '') -- every (returned) string has string library functions attached as method (metatable > metamethod > __index = string)
print(('%d newline/s removed\n%s'):format(count, data))
```

Keep in Mind: string.gsub() loops over the whole string therefore the count return value will show how often the pattern `'\n'` has matched and replaced with an empty string `''` <-- 2 single quotes or if nginx dont allow/accept single quotes you can try `[[]]` or `""`

Comment: Thank you, i'm getting error inside nginx, i had to use double quotes because single quotes are not accepted from nginx lua

I add this line : 

`local data, count = open_file:read("*a"):gsub("\n", "")`

And get :

*1 failed to load inlined Lua code: rewrite_by_lua(conf.conf:81):12: unfinished string near '"

Comment: Try this to replace the empty string: ```gsub("\n", [[]])``` or let a space in:```gsub("\n", " ")```

Answer (score 0):

[`file:read()`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-file:read) only reads a single line. To read the entire file into a string, you have to use `file:read("*a")`.

---

Note however that you also seem to have your arguments to `string.find` swapped: The first argument is the subject string you're searching in and the second argument is the pattern. Since you want to search in the file, you should be using `string.find(data, string1)`.

Comment: Hi @lmd  yes, exactly. 

When i add ("*a") 

And when I test with ngx. say(file) it displays everything

However, it's stopped working string. find, even the first line is stopping giving a positive result.


Is there maybe a method to write all of the lines in one line with space?.



Let me explain my scenario : 
I'm doing post requests to this server with JSON content
and in JSON content there is the number that needs to match with one of my files.

Then if it's match I'm redirecting.